# should metadata collection in mognoose be referenced or it should be inside main collection

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema is as below:

foodtruck.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Items = require('./items.js');


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:{type:Number,default:5},
    foodtruck_total_votes:{type:Number,default:0},
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_open_status:{type:Number,default:1},   //0 open 1 closed
    foodtruck_starting_timing:String,
    foodtruck_closing_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:[String],
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

Now,what I want to do is , I want to add **foodtruck_meta_data :[String]** . should I create another collection **xyz** in which I provide this meta field and then provide **foodtruck_id** as reference ?

Or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three cases here:

1. Meta data is sharable between food trucks and is complex i.e. has multiple fields and is not unique
2. Meta data is sharable between food trucks but it's a simple string
3. Complex or simple, meta data is not sharable (unique for each food truck)

You need a new collection only in case 1 because otherwise you will end up replicating (embedding) the same document in multiple food trucks. However, I would prefer keeping `foodtruck_meta_data_id` in `foodtruck` as it will help to fetch meta data with `populate`.

For 2 `enum` validation is simple yet effective:

```
  foodtruck_meta_data: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['meta1', 'meta2', 'meta3'],
        required: true
      }
```

And you should embed a document or place a string in `foodtruck_meta_data` in case of 3.